# MySQL query for sorting by multiple date values

Tags: database, mysql

I'm creating a PHP script that fetches IDs from a database. The results are sorted by two `datetime` values, `createdon` and `publishon`.

The priority of `publishon` is higher than `createdon`; however, `publishon` may also be `NULL`. `publishon = null` => sort by `createdon`.

Can someone help me sort those rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ORDER BY IFNULL(PublishOn, CreatedOn), CreatedOn
```